# Huge spaces after each figure

Tags: spacing, floats

I have huge spaces after each figure and I wonder what is wrong with my latex code here.

```
\textbf{}\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{This is an image}\label{fig:a}
    \begin{minipage}{.99\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{abc.png}
    \figurenote{This is a figure.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You need to provide more code. BTW: what if up with that `\textbf{}`?

Comment: you could remove `\begin{minipage}{.99\linewidth}` which is doing nothing but the spacing of a float depends on what is on the rest of the page. using `[h]` usually generates a warning as it does not allow the float to be placed anywhere in most cases, not top, not bottom, not on a pag on its own (no `t`, `b`, `p`)

Comment: If for image I use `example-image` which provide LaTeX, and extend your code fragment to complete small document which start with `\documentclass{apa7}\shorttitle{}`, I can't reproduce your problem. So, its cause is not in shown fragment but somewhere else. It may be in your figure which contain a big white border. To see it, insert your figure in `\frame`, likeČ `\frame{
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%{abc.png}
}` and see if frame is not tied to image.